# Looking for a bare-bones open-source editor written in python

Tags: python, open-source, text-editor

I'm looking for a bare bones cross platform editor written in python that I can pick up and customize. The fewer dependencies the better.

Please note: I'm not looking for a python editor or python IDE. Just a no-frills editor, that 
I can use as a base for an app that I'm starting on.

Must be open source and free to modify for commercial use since I intend to use this for work.

Comment: There is also a list of editors written in Python here: http://texteditors.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?PythonEditorFamily

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a complete editor written in [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) here:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxHowtoSmallEditor

Only 104 lines, should be easy to customize.

EDIT:

To address some of your requirements, here is a copy and paste from the [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) wiki:

**A GUI Toolkit**

wxPython is a GUI toolkit for the Python programming language. It allows Python programmers to create programs with a robust, highly functional graphical user interface, simply and easily. It is implemented as a Python extension module (native code) that wraps the popular wxWindows cross platform GUI library, which is written in C++.

**Open Source**

Like Python and wxWindows, wxPython is Open Source which means that it is free for anyone to use and the source code is available for anyone to look at and modify. Anyone can contribute fixes or enhancements to the project.

**Cross Platform**

wxPython is a cross-platform toolkit. This means that with a little care that the same program will run on multiple platforms without modification. Currently supported platforms are Microsoft Windows, and most Unix or unix-like systems with GTK available, and OS X 10.3.9 or above.

Answer (score 2):

How about IDLE? IDLE is included in the standard Python distro. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/idle.html):

"

IDLE has the following features:

- coded in 100% pure Python, using the tkinter GUI toolkit
- cross-platform: works on Windows and Unix
- multi-window text editor with multiple undo, Python colorizing and many other features, e.g. smart indent and call tips
- Python shell window (a.k.a. interactive interpreter)
- debugger (not complete, but you can set breakpoints, view and step)

"

With some work, you could probably rip out the editor component from IDLE.

Have a look in the `idlelib` directory of your Python standard library.

Answer (score 2):

check out:

**Scitilla/SciTE**
http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html

**Editra**
http://editra.org/

both are cross platform and written in Python.  They are full featured editors, but barebones compared to an IDE or such.

Comment: erm, SciTE isn't written in Python...though it is my preferred editor

Thanks for the link to Editra, though, I'll have to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete editor written in wxPython. It has more functionality than the editor suggested by Andre. It does not yet have a stable release though. https://github.com/0b0bby0/wxEditor.git
It depends on how much functionality you want.